# Swift calling a view controller from a different controller or calling an alert from different controller

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I wanted to know if its possible to call an alert or a controller or simplu a function from seperate controller in swift.  I wanted to access my alert from viewcontroller1 to app delegate , i wanna trigger it in app delegate instead of creating of another alert ,  i have a purpose why i want to trigger it in app delegate .is that possible? Thank You . Can i call my alert in view controller 1 in app delegate? and also i wanna call my collection view from view controller 1 in app delegate is that possible?

collection view code

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
//        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
//        print("emong gepili:" , titleArray[indexPath.row])


        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            var a = loggedInUsername
            if ((a?.range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
                  performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSegue", sender: nil)
                print("yolo")
            }else {
                print("do nothing")
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Access", message: "You Can't Add A Chore", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        } else {


            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

            if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row],
                let name = getTempDetails["name"] as? String,
                let id = getTempDetails["id"] as? Int,
                let description = getTempDetails["desc"] as? String,
                let chorereward = getTempDetails["reward"] as? String,
                let choreschedule = getTempDetails["sched"] as? String

                //                let chorescheds = getTempDetails["sched"] as? String

//                let parent = getTempDetails["parent"] as? String,
//                let child = getTempDetails["child"] as? String,
//                let occurrence = getTempDetails["occurrence"] as? String,
//                let status = getTempDetails["date_created"] as? String,
//                let datec = getTempDetails["status"] as? String,
//                let datemod = getTempDetails["date_modified"] as? String {
            {
                let stat = getTempDetails["status"] as! NSDictionary
                let statname = stat["name"]
                let str = getTempDetails["occurrence"] as! NSDictionary
                let strname = str["name"]
```

alert code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Chore Name: \(getTempDetails["name"] as! String)", message: "", preferredStyle:
                    UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


                alert.addTextField { (choreField) in
                    choreField.text = getTempDetails["name"] as! String
                }



                alert.addTextField { (rewardField) in
                    //                    rewardField.text =  getTempDetails["reward"] as! String
                    let rewardData = getTempDetails["reward"]
                    let reward = (rewardData as! NSString).integerValue
                    rewardField.placeholder = "Chore Reward"
                    rewardField.text = String(reward)
                }

                alert.addTextField { (idField) in
                    idField.placeholder = "Email"
                    var a =  "\(getTempDetails["id"] as? Int ?? 0)!"
                    a.removeLast()
                    idField.text = a
                }
                ........
```

Comment: You can create the controller anywhere ... showing is another question

Comment: what i want to know is can i call my alert in my view controller in app delegate?

Comment: Create an extension of `UIViewController`. Then you can call the alert in any view controller.

Comment: Why? It's not really the app delegates responsibility, especially if the view controller isn't currently the top level controller.  I might consider using a notification instead, but that's me

Comment: how about i wanna call this   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { ....... from view controller 1 in app delagate is that possible?

Comment: You must not call `didSelectItemAt` anyway. The method is exclusively called by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my underStanding, You are trying to show an alert during the `AppDelegate`.

But it is not possible to show there, basically what will happen is that `AppDelegate` will be called when the app starts , after that the View controller which is first in the stack will be called.

If you have made any Condition in AppDelegate and in that case want to show alert there,

**You can use**

```
func showAlertAppDelegate(title : String,message : String,buttonTitle : String,window: UIWindow){ 
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) 
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)) 
window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

And use it like:

```
showAlertAppDelegate(title: "Alert!", message: "Message", buttonTitle: "Ok", window: self.window!)
```

**Note:-** This alert will be shown on the first VC that will be loaded after the App delegate is called.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this extension to present Alert or ViewController any where in the Application :**

```
extension UIApplication {
class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(controller: presented)
    }
    return controller
}
```

`}`

**How to use it ?**

```
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(yourAlertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Now What I've understood from your problem,
>
> Clearly calling collection view's delegate methods from AppDelegate is a wrong approach as iOS Geek said it is Singleton.
>   But what you can do you can create a observer for that Like
>   the below one.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(theMethodWhichYouWanaHit(params:)), name: Notification.Name("Notification_Name"), object: nil)
```

Below is the method :

```
func theMethodWhichYouWanaHit(_ params : Notification){
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    let yourObject = params.object
    // use the object it has all the data in it (aka objectToBePassed )
}
```

You're done.!

Now, Just post the observer just like a function call and it will do the rest.:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Notification_Name"), object: objectToPassed, userInfo:nil)
```

In order to remove the observer :

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name("Notification_Name"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new NSObject class and make global function as its class func as shown in Example below

```
  class wrapperClass: NSObject
    {
       class func alert(_ title : String, message : String, view:UIViewController)
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:  message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
wrapperClass.alert("Service Remainder", message: "Enter Username", view: self)
```

**Note** - AppDelgate is not a View controller so You can not Call this function in AppDelegate You can do One thing in the First Controller getting Displayed

Comment: Sir , how about i wanted to call   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { whcih is from view controller i wanna call it it app delegate

Comment: you can not call its a Delegate of CollectionView , is it you want to action to perform itself when Control reached to that respective Controller ?

Comment: AppDelegate is A Singleton class not a ViewController class , its the main File that is respond when app is loaded , All the Actions you need can be done through a Controller

Comment: You will Explicitly need to call the required Delegate when control reaches to a ViewController, By making a Exact Function that will Perform the required Task

Comment: Please DON'T do this. Use @vadian's suggestion to OP's question and add an alert function to an extension of `UIViewController`.

Comment: so its not possible to call it in app delegate?

Comment: No, as its not a ViewController its a Singleton class

Comment: you can take a rootView Controller and initiate that as your launchScreen and use all the checks In that custom Launch Screen which is basically a ViewController